# Can "wrought from" be used in the same context as "caused by" or "formed by?"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, expressions

The most familiar use of *wrought* is probably "wrought iron," as in iron that's malleable and able to be shaped and, for example, made into fences.

All the dictionary definitions of *wrought* are along those lines.

> Full Definition of *wrought* from Merriam Webster:
>
> 1 :  worked into shape by artistry or effort *[carefully wrought
> essays]*
>
> 2 :  elaborately embellished :  ornamented
>
> 3 :  processed for use :  manufactured
> [wrought silk]
>
> 4 :  beaten into shape by tools : hammered — used of metals
>
> 5 :  deeply stirred :  excited — often used
> with up *[gets easily wrought up over nothing]*

So I feel like it would be safe to say that *wrought from* basically means *formed by*. I find that in my writing, I often want to use it in that context, but I always hesitate and feel unsure whether it would be correct.

The example I'm currently working with is a character looking at all the calluses on their hands, which are the result of handling a variety of tools and weaponry. The sentence would go something like this:

> *Her own calluses, wrought from years of handling those same tools and weapons, would probably never fade.*

I feel like *wrought from* makes sense here (by which I mean a reader would at least understand what I was talking about), but I'm not sure if it's technically correct to use it this way. Anyone have any thoughts or definitive answers?

Comment: I'd say "wrought" and "formed" could work as rough synonyms in your context, but you can't change the preposition "from" to "by": that inverts subject and object. A sword is wrought *from* iron, but wrought *by* a blacksmith.

Comment: @DanBron ooh good point. So it would need to either be "wrought/formed by" or "wrought/formed from", but not "wrought from/formed by." I see what you mean.

Comment: Right. Also just FYI the connotations of the two words differ slightly, and therefore lend different nuances to your usage.  "Wrought" means "worked, created" *by a sentient agent*, whereas "formed" is neutral in the sense of agency. Sand dunes are *formed* over centuries of accumulation, but they are *wrought* by the relentless desert winds (i.e. in this latter case you're anthropomorphising the winds).

Comment: @DanBron that makes sense. I've been sitting here trying to decide whether or not the aforementioned calluses are the result of physically touching the tools and weapons (which I guess they technically would be) or whether they're the result of "years of using" those tools and weapons. The latter is a more abstract concept, and that's something to take into consideration when it comes to word choice...hmm

Answer (score 4):

I would not employ *wrought* (or its modern form *worked*) to express the process by which calluses are formed.

It seems to me that these words imply agency and volition: somebody deliberately sets out to *work* their material into the desired form. Even the metaphorical extension to emotional states implies agency: when we say someone is "wrought up" we suggest that they have *worked themselves up* into anger or distress.

But calluses are an incidental by-product of the activity on which a craftsman is focused. I feel that speaking of calluses as *wrought* would be rather precious even among those artists such as guitarists and baseball pitchers who welcome the calluses: [this source](https://www.guitartricks.com/blog/How-to-Toughen-Up-Your-Fingertips), for instance, offers tips for assuring that calluses will develop but insists that

> The most effective way to build calluses is through good old-fashioned practice.
> [. . .]
> Keep playing regularly. Learn to embrace the pain, knowing it will pass. Don't let sore fingertips stand between you and your dream of playing guitar. Don't give up, toughen up.
>
> And finally, remember that you've worked hard for your calluses. Keep them the same way you earned them—practice, practice, and more practice—and your tips will serve you a lifetime.